# How to include css files into compojure project?

Tags: css, clojure, compojure, ring

I'm learning clojure and I work on project where I'm using ***compojure*** & ***ring*** & ***clostache*** *(mustache for clojure)*.

This is my core clojure file:

```
(defroutes public-routes
       (GET "/" [] (controller/index))
       (route/resources "/")
       (GET "/index" [] (controller/index))
       (route/resources "/")
       (GET "/customers" [] (controller/customers))
       (route/resources "/")
       (GET "/employees" [] (controller/employees))
       (route/resources "/")
    )

(defroutes app-routes   public-routes
           (route/not-found "404 Not Found")
           )
```

My question is: How I can **include CSS files** in my .*mustache* files? Is this problem related to .*mustache* extension or something about compojure way of working?

PS: With link tag css file is not found (404).

Comment: Where are your css files? Can you fetch them at all? (e.g. by going to localhost:port/css/yourfile.css in your browser).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created the project using compojure template with `lein`, then there is a directory under your project root named `${project_root}/resources/public`. The static files like `.html`, `.js,`, `.css` can reside in the directory.

For example, you can make the directory structure like this:

```
${project_root}/resources/public/index.html
                                /js/util.js
                                /css/style.css
```

In the above structure, you can access `index.html` by `/index.html`, and `style.css` by `/css/style.css`, and so on.

Comment: I had no public folder in resources. Thanks a lot! :)