# How to include a .js file into an html file that is served by a compojure server?

Tags: javascript, clojure, compojure

One of my html file needs to include a script file, as it often happens, and no matter what I do, the browser doesn't seem to get it.

following this answer: [How to include css files into compojure project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484636/how-to-include-css-files-into-compojure-project)

I created a public folder in my resource folder. The structure looks like this:

```
resources
|-public
  |-views
  |   |-myview.html
  |-scripts
     |-my.script.js
```

Inclusion of the file in myview.html looks like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="/scripts/my.script.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I request myview.html from the server I get it, but all of the types in my.script.js are unknown. The html works as expected when I just load it in the browser (I have to adjust the path to the script file to be relative, of course, and no, that doesn't work either when I request it from my server).

So how do I get my script files (and later css files) to be found by the html in a typical compojure setup?

Comment: just a basic basic checks first... are you using the default ring middleware? (see, for example, the stuff in this template: https://github.com/weavejester/compojure-template )--- my loose suspicion is that something is wrong with your headers, but that should be handled by ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was just missing

```
(route/resources "/")
```

in my routing. As that wasn't the problem with the topic I looked at, I didn't figure it out for a while.
Turns out sometimes you should read the code in the question just as carefully as the answer...